# Unable to run jMeter 5.0 on Windows 8.1 via the jMeter.bat

Tags: java, apache, jmeter, windows-8.1, jmeter-5.0

I'm having difficulty running jMeter 5.0 via the jmeter.bat file on Windows 8.1.  I've been using jMeter 3.0 successfully via the jmeter.bat file. The bat file for the 3.0 version in this directory, and works:

> C:\Downloads\jMeter 3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin

The jMeter 5.0 version sits in this directory, and fails:

> C:\Downloads\jMeter 5.0\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin

Error it produces:

```
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Dpropname=value
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
errorlevel=1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Do I need to tweak the jmeter.bat file or install something else first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMeter's JVM settings [increased](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html) by default and you can update [jmeter.bat](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/bin/jmeter.bat) file with your required settings overriding `JVM_ARGS=...` or `HEAP`

> JMeter JVM heap settings have changed from -Xms512m -Xmx512m to -Xms1g -Xmx1g
>
> HEAP        - (Optional) JVM memory settings used when starting JMeter
>                   Defaults to '-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m'

Comment: Thanks, so I see this line in an "if not defined HEAP" block:  set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m  <-- Should I change this to a different value?

Comment: @KenPalmer try old values `-Xms512m -Xmx512m` you can set in setenv.bat see https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#running

Comment: Thanks for that tip on the setenv.bat. Originally it was set to this:  set JVM_ARGS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Dpropname=value" -- After setting it to this the bat file works:  set JVM_ARGS="-Dpropname=value"